# Hide warnings from R console

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to hide warnings from console when I run my shiny app
I tried adding this to my ui

```
tags$style(type="text/css",
         ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
         ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
)
```

but it is not working
please help
thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppress warning message in R console of shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652658/suppress-warning-message-in-r-console-of-shiny)

Comment: there are many warnings .. one of them is 
Warning: Mangling the following names:....  Use enc2native() to avoid the warning. 
(the app contains arabic characters and this warning come out many times)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the best way to hide those red error messages. You likely see those some output depends on an input that is yet defined.

See this app below:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("datasetName", "Dataset", c("", "pressure", "cars")),
  plotOutput("plot"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dataset <- reactive({
    get(input$datasetName, "package:datasets", inherits = FALSE)
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(dataset())
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    head(dataset(), 10)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

By simply placing `req(input$datasetName)` where `input$datasetName` is needed: the `reactive` we get rid of those.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("datasetName", "Dataset", c("", "pressure", "cars")),
  plotOutput("plot"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dataset <- reactive({
    req(input$datasetName) # add req
    get(input$datasetName, "package:datasets", inherits = FALSE)
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(dataset())
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    head(dataset(), 10)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `css` that you have posted is to prevent red error messages from showing up on the Shiny app itself.

To suppress warning messages from showing up in the console when someone else runs the app themselves from R/RStudio, maybe most flexible is if you use `options(warn = -1)`. See also `?warning`. Then you can just override it to `options(warn = 0)` when you would like to see the warnings.
In this scenario it would be advisible to make sure you set the warning level back to zero (*better in fact to whatever it was previously*) with `options(warn = 0)` whenever the app exits (see `?on.exit`), else you may confuse your users.

An alternative would be to use `suppressWarnings` as suggested in the link of the comment, which is safer in this regard. You could still make it depend on an option such that you could override it for your own purposes.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am sorry but I don't understand where shoud I add
options(warn = -1)

Comment: depends on your setup - if you use a `global.R` file you could put it there, if you have one single file with `ui`, `server` and `runApp()`, you can put it at the very top

Comment: then I think you need to show more of your setup / code in the question, such that we can understand better what could be going wrong here. else it's hard to help