# How to suppress not traditional warnings in R Console for Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, warnings, xgboost

[image]

I have an R Shiny app. And I am making predictions from 10k xgboost models in the app. And the R console will show such error each time I make a prediction from a single model:

```
[23:13:24] WARNING: amalgamation/../src/objective/regression_obj.cu:152: reg:linear is now deprecated in favor of reg:squarederror.
```

Some explanations about this warning can be found here: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/4599

(I don't have time and can't rerun these models to fix the warnings now.)

Also, notice this is not a normal warning from the Shiny because this error is in black color and also showing in the specific form (see above).

I tried to use `suppressWarnings` function on my `predict` and other method such as the first reply in this thread: [Suppress warning message in R console of shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652658/suppress-warning-message-in-r-console-of-shiny)

But I still have the warnings. I think there are 10k warnings and my result will be shown on the Shiny interface after all the warnings are loaded, which is a big slow-down.

So anyone knows how to solve this? Or even a global way, such as suppress any output in R console while running a Shiny app.

Thanks in advance!!